# (Visual Studio)Build time takes longer if compiled as a project and shorter if compiled alone

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, compilation

I have a cpp file which takes about 10 seconds to compile if I just right-click and do compile it on Visual studio, but takes insane amount of time when compiled as a project together(where this cpp file is 1 among 20 others).

Compiling separately:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Xcp.Test.Boost, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>  XcpOnEthernetDisconnectSendTest.cpp
1>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c1xx.dll)=5.196s
1>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=5.826s
1>
```

Compiled with project:

```
21>  XcpOnEthernetDisconnectSendTest.cpp
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c1xx.dll)=4.693s
21>  Generating Code...
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=5.204s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=6.736s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=4.203s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=2.118s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=1.980s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=1.711s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=1.547s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=2.327s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=2.410s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=5.140s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=4.439s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=5.175s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=6.389s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=3.393s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=2.289s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=0.341s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=2.098s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=1.083s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=0.399s
21>  time(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\c2.dll)=0.006s
```

also, I don't get to see multiple compile time results for other file but for this particular file. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: The time after `Generating Code...` seems to be measuring linking time (is LTO enabled?). Also you should figure out why does it take so long to build just a single file. Most likely there is a template bloat or something.

Comment: @VTT The code uses templates heavily, in fact all other cpp files in the project also uses templates heavily. but only this file takes this long, and why do you think the time after "generating code..." is measuring linking time? could you please explain and why so many linking needed for same file?

Comment: Heavy use of templates does not imply long build times. You are clearly dealing with bloat of some sort. If you build whole project then it will be linked afterwards. If LTO is enabled in some form then it will involve generating code using compilation results from all the compiled files which is supposed to be considerably slower than compiling each file individually.

Comment: Apparently, all the time slots mentioned above are the linking time of all other files which are compiled as a part of project compilation. @VTT Thanks for pointing that out.